# Joomla custom module additional layout

Tags: layout, joomla, module

How is it possible to select an additional layout in a custom module?
I created a second layout in /modules/custom_module/tmpl/default2, but I cannot select this layout. At advanced settings 'alternative layout' it is only possible to select default.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot. I found the problem. When the layout is called with an _ it is not possible to see the layouts in modules alternative layout. This means layout-new will be found and layout_new won't be found. This is also true by Joomla's core modules. I dont know why, iam using Joomla 3.3.3?!

Answer (score -1):

Alternative layouts are search for in your template. If you want to have two layout options in the module itself you would need to do something similar to the login module where the sublayouts are called. This would probably be a good topic for http://joomla.stackexchange.com.

Comment: when I look into the login module (Joomla 3), I cannot see additional layouts. It is also only standard available. Thank you for your link, but this one is to less specific.

Comment: mod_login most definitely has default and default_logout.

Comment: you are right! but in the administrators backend, I can only choose default at the modules->advanced settings->alternative layout. There is no option default_logout. Same situation at my custom module. Only default available?

Comment: This is what I said in my first comment.  YOu put alternative layouts in your template not in the module. If you want the core module to have choices of layouts you will need to supply the layouts there and add a parameter to select which one you want or do what the login module does which is to change the layout depending on if the user is logged in (and using a subtemplate).

Comment: This is not true at all. Modules are allowed to have included alternative layouts, it doesn't need to be a layout override in the template.

Comment: Of course a module an have an alternative layout, but if you are adding your own to an existing module (not one you are making yourself) you would put it in the template.